# Length of the decryption(RSA) string is changing

Tags: java, algorithm, security, aes, rsa

I have a String which is encrypted with RSA algorithm, When i was trying to decrypt it's working fine.The decryption output will be in byte[].

My question is when i trying to convert the byte[] to  a new String(decrypted String) it's getting different length .

If i try with a random string the length is remains  same.But if i decrypt the 
generated aesKey(AES) the length of the byte[] is changing while conversion of new String(decrypted String).

Why i am getting different length incase of aesKey decryption???
Is there any difference between "random string" and "generated aeskey"

String ==
"t8xypyI6gKlKTkt4Qec7FCor4EpukZXqYQcIDm6YvbtRB9+YBrX0CqyoHOHN91T8RBQS/JD2osbf4ao9Y"SgNbzhfDa2NpJKMEIBWH4TNlF4Ngb8yWdSm3hz3l8FdeFUIy3pyCxkLjU8n4VAxsmgoIQbgd7DJuPiSMZBA9/IVlcCfo/tZjMtSkezITtoT5aVvLxLaTsp08UREdalvXxb5USKi3cAEdqR9TmLJxB004IMv5Eiuvdmcc3fJzO6mnwiHPuGKArd9LjjiqbPQ75uc8NDOFrvleLc5KwSuThS5Xx7tR1qfoX6qefh6SD7FRk5UzyCEnv+eD+mCQ588Jam1A==";

****The above string is encrypted form of the aesKey(generated by KeyGenerator)

If i decrypt this string by using RSA----

```
private String decrypt(String text, Key privatekey) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
    byte[] dectyptedText = null;

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privatekey);
    dectyptedText = cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(text));
    System.out.println(dectyptedText.length);                  //32
    System.out.println(new String(dectyptedText).length());    //30
    System.out.println(new String(dectyptedText).getBytes().length); //60
    return new String(dectyptedText);

}
```

above, The length is  changing in byte string conversions.

Suppose if i encrypt and decrypt with a normal string the lengths are not changing????why????

Comment: share the code. I'm not sure what is your problem.

Comment: yes,I shared the code Please look into it once..

Comment: I cannot make sense of your question. First you're talking about a String, then you're talking about an AES key. It makes no sense to convert an AES key to a String using the `new String()` constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely, the `decryptedText` contains funny bytes. The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte%5B%5D)) says:

> `public String(byte[] bytes)`
>
> Constructs a new `String` by decoding the specified array of bytes **using the platform's default charset**. The length of the new String is a function of the charset, and hence **may not be equal to the length of the byte array**.
>
> The behavior of this constructor when the given bytes are not valid in the default charset is unspecified. The CharsetDecoder class should be used when more control over the decoding process is required.

Comment: I'd bet OP's charset is UTF-8. AESkey is effectively random bytes, and statistically nearly half of them are invalid UTF-8; although not spec'ed in reality decoding substitutes U+FFFD which then re-encodes to 3 bytes, so you get a random length near 16+(3x16)=64 bytes. With the actual AES key value destroyed, of course. So don't do that.

Comment: Right, If we convert the String to byte[]---> byte[] to String behavior is not changing, if we convert the byte[] to new String , The length of the byte[] is changing, it's might effect on the byte[].